# Unable to connect to MySql database on a Remote linux server from a windows GUI tool

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I have setup a mysql database on a linux server on Amazon's EC2.  This works well locally.  I can log into the linux box and administer the mysql database

I am trying to connect my local GUI client to the remote mysql and it is failing to connect.

I updated the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and changed the following:

```
skip-networking
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

I am still not able to connect.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: I first tried bind-address=0.0.0.0 , then I added skip-networking with bind-address

**EDIT #2**: I made sure the security group opens on 3306.  I also have other ports open which work so I dont think its an amazon specific issue

Comment: skip-networking will disable TCP connection support. You'll be limited to connecting via UNIX-domain sockets only. The bind-address will be useless as well, since TCP isn't enabled.

Comment: I had a similar problem and i had created the instance in one region and then tried to connect in another and it failed

Comment: Did you check security group? Open the port 3306 and allow your IP.

Comment: Yes. I checked the security group

Comment: @PurplePilot:  How did you work around the issue?

Comment: LIke I said before, specifying "skip-networking" TURNS OFF tcp networking in MySQL. You won't be able to connect no matter how many ports you open. You have to REMOVE the skip-networking option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally don't recommend you to open port 3306 for public access (or even with IP restrictions). I personally always tunnel port 3306 with Putty/ssh and then just use localhost to connect to the database.

In this case don't forget to grant privileges for the user like this:

```
grant all privileges on yourDatabaseName.* to 'yourUserName'@'localhost' identified by "yourUsersPassword";
```

If you still want to make direct connection, it's possible, that your user still don't have enough privileges. You can try this:

```
grant all privileges on yourDatabaseName.* to 'yourUserName'@'yourClientsIp' identified by "yourUsersPassword";
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Read http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html for instructions on how to do it with PuTTY.